# Jenkins Configure Global Security from bash script

Tags: bash, groovy, jenkins

I'd like to configure Jenkins from a bash script.

The action is to enable global security and use Unix user/group database for it.

Can I just copy some configuration XMLs and restart the server? Or there is a groovy script to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's it:

```
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.security.*

def instance = Jenkins.getInstance()

def unixRealm = new PAMSecurityRealm("ssh")
instance.setSecurityRealm(unixRealm)

instance.setAuthorizationStrategy(new FullControlOnceLoggedInAuthorizationStrategy())

instance.save()
```